# Why do I have an 'invalid column name' when I try to sum two columns with alias that contains a space?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like this :

```
SELECT 
    SUM (case when cat = '1' then time else 0 end) as 'Play 1-2d',
    SUM (case when cat = '2' then time else 0 end) as 'Play 3-10d',
    SUM (case when cat = '3' then time else 0 end) as 'Play +30d'
FROM PlayingTime
```

What I'm trying to do is to sum all the value from my select (and not from the table `PlayingTime`)

So I tried this :

```
SELECT 
    SUM (case when cat = '1' then time else 0 end) as 'Play 1-2d',
    SUM (case when cat = '2' then time else 0 end) as 'Play 3-10d',
    SUM (case when cat = '3' then time else 0 end) as 'Play +30d',
    [Play 1-2d]+[Play 3-10d]+[Play +30d]
FROM PlayingTime
```

But with this I have an `Invalid column name` error with all my column.

I think it's because the alias has a space inside it ? Because when I use an underscore it works.

So, my question is : how can I sum my columns without changing my alias names?

Comment: Because you can't reference a calculated column in the same scope that it is created.

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals, not identifiers. Use square brackets, or double quotes, instead.

Comment: `case` is spelled with only 1 a.

Comment: @jarlh I know, but when I spell it with one a I can't post the question. Ok I see thank you all :)

Comment: Q : `how can I sum my columns without changing my alias names?` A : use `CTE` or `Derived Table`

Comment: Or you could just write out all three values again